# Tabla en php cree una nueva tabla cada cierta cantidad de registros

Tags: php

Hola necesito ayuda con generar una tabla dinamica que cada 3 registros me agregue una nueva fila
En la imagen muestro como me esta imprimiendo las imagenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo hago mediante div pero lo quiero pasar a tabla que cada 3 imagenes me cree una nueva tabla
este es el codigo para mostrar las imagenes

```
 <div class="Galeria">
            <?php            
                $Resp = busqueda_catalogo_avanzadado($buscar,$condiciones,$where,$whereTipo);
                while ($row = $Resp->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <div class="item sliderMchapGaleria">
               <a class="linkImagenes" href="vistaPieza?id=<?php echo $row["numero"]?>&cat=<?php echo $row["Categoria"] ?>">
               <div class="GaleriaPrincipal descripcionMchap readme">      
                    <div class="item">
                        <figure>
                            <div class="sliderItem">
                                <div class="imgSlider">
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?><?php echo $row["ruta_imagen"] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="infoSlider">
                                    <div class="span1Slider">
                                        <div class="Contenedor-Texto-Titulo"><?php echo $row["Titulo"]; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row span2Slider">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-left">
                                            <div class="Contenedor-Texto-SubTituloRight"><?php echo $row["Cultura"]; ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                            <div class="Contenedor-Texto-SubTituloLeft"><?php echo $row["annio"]; ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3Slider">
                                        <div class="Contenedor-Texto-SubTitulo"><?php echo $row["numero"]; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
               </div>    
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// estos son los supuestos registros, imágenes o lo que sean para  
// componer la tabla iterando los elementos
$rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,];

$NUMBER_BY_ROW = 3; // número de imágenes que quieres mostrar por fila
$rowCounter = 1; // lo usó para imprimir un header h4 oculto en cada fila

echo '<nav class="item sliderMchapGaleria">';
echo '<section class="row">'; // abre la primera fila
echo '<h4 hidden>Fila número '.$rowCounter.'</h4>';


foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    printItemBox($row);
    if ((($key + 1) % $NUMBER_BY_ROW) === 0) {
        $rowCounter++;
        echo '</section>'; // cierra fila anterior
        echo '<section class="row">'; // abre nueva fila
        echo '<h4 hidden>Fila número '.$rowCounter.'</h4>';
    }
}
echo '</section>'; // cierra la última fila
echo '</nav>';

function printItemBox($row): void
{
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo $row;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Con este script tienes un HTML como el siguiente (quizas quieras ajustarlo para que si generar cajas vacías en la última fila):

```
<nav class="item sliderMchapGaleria">
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 1</h4>
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 2</h4>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 3</h4>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 4</h4>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item">11</div>
        <div class="item">12</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 5</h4>
        <div class="item">13</div>
        <div class="item">14</div>
        <div class="item">15</div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
        <h4 hidden>Fila número 6</h4>
        <div class="item">16</div>
    </section>
</nav>
```

He usado el resto, para calcular el número de elementos que va en cada fila, para el caso 3. Se puede modificar este valor asignando un número diferente a la variable `$NUMBER_BY_ROW`.